# rails namespaced route with root only works in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
namespace :admin do 
  root :to => "admin#index"
end
```

I can visit `localhost:3000/admin` and it works.
When I deploy to heroku `myapp.herokuapp.com/admin` does not. It produced this

`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Admin::AdminController):`

My controller is actually AdminController, not Admin::AdminController and I'm not quite sure what the difference is or how to fix this.

Again, it all works locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in `rake routes` output that for this namespaced route rails uses `:controller => 'admin/admin'`. When it comes to finding controller class it converts `admin/admin` into `Admin::AdminController`. So controllers for namespaced routes are usually placed under `app/controllers/namespace_name` directory and wrapped in `NamespaceName` module. In your case it should be `Admin::AdminController` class defined in `app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb`.

Though, it's really interesting why your configuration works fine in development but breaks in production mode (I tried and successfully reproduced it). I believe it has smth to do with loading and caching classes in production mode, because setting `config.cache_classes = true` in `config/environments/development.rb` cause it breaking in development mode as well.

And as *zoltarSpeaks* noted it's supposed to be `root :to => "admin#index"` instead of `root :to => "Admin#index"`.

Another thing to note is that namespaces for routes are usually used when there are multiple related controllers. If all you need is single `AdminController` you can config your routes like that:

```
resources :admin, :only => :index
```

In that case no other changes are needed (if you want to have other default actions besides `index` just remove `:only` option).

Comment: the route actually shows `/admin` for me. But putting it in an admin folder and using the Admin::AdminController syntax worked. The only problem is my folder structure for views is somewhat less clean views/admin/admin/index.html.erb (this is perhaps what you meant by admin/admin?) previously I had /admin/index.html.erb along with folders for other admin section controllers.

Comment: Oh, now I'm seeing a problem. I have 2 other controllers as part of my admin system which are defined like: `Admin::OrdersController < AdminController` visiting those controllers produces this error: `uninitialized constant AdminController`

Comment: For that purpose I usually define base admin controller as `Admin::ApplicationController` and then other controllers as `Admin::OrdersController < Admin::ApplicationController`. Though, in my case this base `ApplicationController` controller usually doesn't have any views and contains only stuff that is later used in other admin controllers (like, for example, before-filters).

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from my laptop so can't check but is:

```
root :to => "Admin#index"
```

supposed to be:

```
root :to => "admin#index"
```

instead? It might not make any difference.

Do you have an Admin folder within controllers with an Admin controller inside it then?

If you could show us your controller code too it would be helpful thanks.

Comment: The capital "A" was just a typo in my question, sorry. I do not have my admin controller inside the admin folder, but other sub-controllers are in an admin controller. I've tried placing the admin controller in that folder as well.